# Mixing two query in one

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I used a statement to change query according by value, if value (`$dist`) exist in array (`$disArray`) it should run first query (first `$addq`) if not should use second one.

```
$dist = 54; //or $dist = 2;
$disArray = array(54, 67, 102);

if(in_array($dist,$disArray)){
    $disId = getDisById($dist);
    $addq = "AND district.dis IN ($disId)";  
} else {
    $addq = "AND ads.district IN ($dist)";
}

$query = "SELECT ... //some other query, left join..// FROM items WHERE st = 1 $addq";
```

In this example, if value equal 54 it execute first query, and if 2 (or other number that not exist in array) it execute second query, now my problem is when `$dist` be an array, how should use this statement for two query in same time? for example:

```
 $dist = 54, 2;
```

The problem is, if it be an array that mixed of a number for first query and another for second query, it now work as I expected, it just run one query, but I want to run both query in a same time.

So it should find `district.dis` in 54 and `ads.district` in 2.

Comment: `if(){}elseif(){}else{}`

Comment: Hopefully using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli)...  This type of code makes an ORM like Doctrine attractive in my opinion. Treat the SQL statement in an OOP fashion... `$stmt->andWhere('...')`; Otherwise it gets messy fast with `implode()` all over and worrying about trailing 'AND''s and commas.

Comment: @rtfm What do you mean, I think you not understand the question. `else if` what? If you have answer, please make it. I don't think `else if` work. How can I detect and separate numbers based on an array and two query!

Comment: @ficuscr I using `mysqli` but not prepared statment.

Comment: He is saying an 'elseif' would let you actually evaluate for the scenarios you describe. I.e it ain't a binary thing. IF 1, IF 2, IF 1&2...

Comment: It is just really hard to understand what you are asking... Try to clean up you question, especially the part below the code block

Comment: @jonasfh Believe me, if you read code block, it's clear. if value = 54, so 54 exist in array, so it should use first query, right? okay now if value = 2, it is not in array, so it should use second query. alright, now if value like an array and has two string, like `$dist = 54, 2, 33, 208;` now what? It just run one query but it should run both in same time, in one single query.

Comment: `$dist = 54, 2, 33, 208;` is not even valid php, you also call it an array (which its not), so i dont know what values you are actually working with

Comment: @rtfm It took from query string, why it is not valid? I told **like** an array. I mean it has two value in one string, separated by comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a loop that puts the values in separate variables, then combine both conditions with `OR` in the query.

```
$dist = "54,2";
$distToArray = explode(",", $dist);

$district_dis = array();
$ads_district = array();
foreach ($distToArray as $d) {
    if (in_array($d, $disArray)) {
        $district_dis[] = getDisById($d);
    } else {
        $ads_district[] = $d;
    }
}
$conditions = array();
if (!empty($district_dis)) {
    $conditions[] = "district.dis IN (" . implode(',', $district_dis) . ")";
}
if (!empty($ads_district)) {
    $conditions[] = "ads.district IN (" . implode(',', $ads_district) . ")";
}
if (!empty($conditions)) {
    $addq = "AND (" . implode(' OR ', $conditions) . ")";
} else {
    $addq = "";
}
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected 'in' (T_STRING), expecting ';' in `for ($d in $dist) {`

Comment: Sorry, but now error is `syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS), expecting ';' in`

Comment: Duh, obviously it should be `foreach`, not `for`.

Comment: Well, It not working as what I expected, After debugging, I found out it not  read your statement, first if, second if not even third if. not if inside the loop. after I used your code it just show all result.

Comment: You want the rows where either condition is true or the rows where both conditions are true. I thought it was *either*, so I use `OR`. If it should be both, use `AND`.

Comment: Change `OR` to `AND` .. nothing change, still return all result and not read your condition. Forget it, thanks for your help, after two answer, still I stuck, I should handle it myself, Thanks for your time, I know my question is unclear due my bad english or being newbie to php, for this reason none of these answers solve my problem.

Comment: Because `$dist` not an `array` but a `string` and obviously `foreach` won't work. As **@ficuscr** said in comment you need to convert `string` to `array` then **@Barmar** solution should work! See edited version.

Comment: @Pedram The question says "now my problem is when `$dist` be an array" so I assumed he already changed it to an array himself.

Answer (score 1):

From what we can make sense of the question it is a simple conditional logic question. This is what rtfm was referring to. I'm with jonasfh, in that I'm confused about what you're asking here.

```
<?php

$dist1 = 2;
$dist2 = 54;
$disArray = [54, 67, 102];

if (in_array([$dist1, $dist2], $disArray)) {
    //both    
} elseif (in_array($dist1, $disArray)) {
    //just $dist1
} elseif (in_array($dist2, $disArray)) {
    //just $dist2
} else {
    //none of the above
}
```

Don't overlook the importance in the order of the conditions.

Comment: You wrote 2 in one variable and 54 in another. my question is when it is => `$dist = 54, 2, 5, 102;` It took from query string. and it is one variable not two.

Comment: `FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected ',' on line number 1` As already stated by rtfm that isn't even valid PHP.

Comment: The URL is `&d=54%2C55` and `$_GET["d"]` === 54,55, I just wrote these numbers in a variable. Actually `$dist = $_GET["d"]`

Comment: `explode(',', $_GET['d']) === [$dist1, $dist2]` Not confusing with short array syntax right?  `[1, 2] === array(1,2)`.

Comment: Okay it turn into an array, now what? the comment line in your answer `//both` the problem is here, how can I use both query in one single query?

Comment: `$addq = "AND ( district.dis IN ($disId) OR ads.district IN ($dist) )";`

Comment: So I tested, but look like something wrong, It just run `else` condition. It would be great if you update your answer with the result of our comments. Maybe I missed something.